# Accessing node and yarn on CPanel consistently

Tags: linux, cpanel

I have node.js and yarn installed on my web server. When I log in as root user, I can never use them directly, and command like node --version, or yarn --version will say command not found. I changed my bash_profile file for each user so they can use them, but many times I will get file permission errors, and generally speaking I'd like to be able to easily access both nod and yarn from root access. Is there a way to export PATH for both yarn and node without having a bash_profile file?